# Fantasy novel - Female protagonist with one arm

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

I remember reading a story a few years ago and couldn't afford to get the rest of the series, and since then, it has disappeared off of my kindle. It's a story about a society that treats people with "special abilities" or that look different into a different part of the city and aren't allowed to roam the streets where the "upper class" people live.

Anyhow, the main character is a female, and she is missing an arm. It starts with her and a friend in a club on the other side of the city (the nice side) and a guy notices her missing arm and blurts it out. All hell breaks loose and she and her friend have to book it before the authorities catch them.

Her missing arm is actually because of what she is, but she doesn't know this until she runs back into the guy from the club and he tells her.

Comment: When did you read this? Like one year ago? five? ten?

Comment: Also, what were the "magical" elements? (I ask this since you've tagged with the 'magic' tag).

Comment: Please also check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if you can add any more details. Good luck!

Comment: "*Her missing arm is actually because of what she is*" - so what is she?

Answer (score 10):

I figured out what the book is called now. I FINALLY found it after searching through Amazon for a couple of days. It's called "[The Avoidables](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24859785-avoidables)" By Rachel Medhurst.

> Avoidables have defects ranging from looks to unexplained gifts. Some of us are half breeds. Dragons and animals were known to have bred with the human race thousands of years ago. We all live in cities, usually divided in two. The Perfects live on the Upper Side, while the Avoidables inhabit the Lower Side. We've been consumed by hate for a race that rejects us so heartlessly. We've become dangerous. All we want is the Perfects to love and respect us. Follow Hope, Purple and Jason on their individual journeys. Hope uncovers a great secret about herself when she meets Jason, a Perfect that brings out the best in her. Purple tries to rescue a kidnaped Hope, but soon realises that she's in better company than they knew. When he meets Alia, he's determined not to follow his best friends footsteps in love. Jason needs to prove himself. Avoidables view him as the Perfect mummy's boy, but he will find a way to show Hope that he is perfect for her.

The missing arm is mentioned in [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1513588823?book_show_action=true):

> The book truly is a romance - all about love - specifically between the female main character that jumps quite soon from not having one of her arms - to suddenly regrowing a new on along a brand new set of wings.
>   And probably the reason why I couldn't fully appreciate it.

Comment: Feel free to [accept](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer to help any future visitors.

Comment: If anyone is interested, apparently the book name was changed to [Angel Awakening: Avoidables Book 1](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B01N33UF1E/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_bibl_vppi_i32) and is the first of 4.